# Creation of a large std::array causes segfault?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc

I want to create a large `std::array` and fill it with random data. The problem is that if I declare std::array program segfaults (GDB says it segfaults on `auto start..`) if i comment array declaration program runs.

Here is SCSE:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

static const constexpr size_t size = 1E7;

int main(){

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::array<uint16_t, size> random_data;
    // Here I want to fill random_data with random numbers to avoid 
    // filling memory twice
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end-start;
    std::cout << "Elapsed sec " << elapsed.count() << std::endl;

}
```

It is compiled in gcc using `-std=gnu++11` on GNU/Linux.

Comment: You know the array goes on the stack in this case, right?

Comment: Do you (1) need the data to be contiguous (2) need it all at once?

Comment: @doctorlove I'm doing some ilustrative microbenchmark that compares C++ and python numpy execution speed. In this case I want data to be needed all at once! In another benchmark I'd happliy use C++ some generator that will store data but I couldn't find. In the end I want to do: ``auto sum_result = std::accumulate(random_data->begin(), random_data->end(), static_cast<uint64_t>(0), std::plus<uint64_t>());`` . If you know how to create a generator object that will enable me to use boost/std random number generator and be usable from ``std::accumulate`` please give a hint.

Comment: If only C++ had `yield`... :-) I here it might one day.I guess you could write your own streaming iterators.

Comment: +1 for posting a stack overflow on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `array` lies on the stack, and so does its member, the underlying array. But the stack on your machine is presumably not forty megabytes large, so your program crashes.

Use `vector`.

```
std::vector<std::uint16_t> random_data(size);
```

Or, if you want to avoid unnecessary initialization and don't need dynamic change in size, use a `unique_ptr` holding an array.

```
std::unique_ptr<std::uint16_t[]> random_data( new std::uint16_t[size] );
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b013c68b5b11f18b).